Import theme from Material3 theme builder to Kotlin Multiplatform project
I activated material3 on a KMP (Android/iOS) project by adding this dependency in commonMain: implementation(compose.material3)
Now I was hoping to use the material theme builder to create a theme: https://material-foundation.github.io/material-theme-builder/
It gives me several files that lack dependencies/imports.
This needs to be written as expect/actual with an iOS and Android version it seems:
  val colorScheme = when {
      dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
          val context = LocalContext.current
          if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
      }
      
      darkTheme -> darkScheme
      else -> lightScheme
  }

And it also seems to lack a dependency on androidx.compose.ui:ui-text-google-fonts. I tried importing this in commonMain but it doesn't seem to be KMP compatible.
Any suggestion how to make this work or recommendation for alternatives?

A majority of the errors in themes created with the Material Theme Builder occur because the themes generated by the builder are meant to be used for native Android applications. I made the following changes to make the theme work for Kotlin Multiplatform:
General Note: Be sure to change the package from com.example.compose to your package in all the relevant files.
1. Modify Theme.kt:
Assuming you have placed the ui folder in the same folder which contains your App.kt in the commonMain configuration, the first step would be to remove Android-specific code in Theme.kt. Remove these imports:
import android.app.Activity 
import android.os.Build
import androidx.compose.material3.dynamicDarkColorScheme
import androidx.compose.material3.dynamicLightColorScheme
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext

Then, remove this code snippet. This needs to be written in the androidMain configuration as dynamic color themes are only supported in Android:
@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable() () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> darkScheme
        else -> lightScheme
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = AppTypography,
        content = content
    )
}


Modify Type.kt:

In Type.kt, the libraries used by default will not work as they are platform-specific and can be used in native Jetpack Compose code only.
So remove the following imports and code snippets from Type.kt:
import androidx.compose.ui.text.googlefonts.GoogleFont
import androidx.compose.ui.text.googlefonts.Font

val provider = GoogleFont.Provider(
    providerAuthority = "com.google.android.gms.fonts",
    providerPackage = "com.google.android.gms",
    certificates = R.array.com_google_android_gms_fonts_certs
)

val bodyFontFamily = FontFamily(
    Font(
        googleFont = GoogleFont("Poppins"),
        fontProvider = provider,
    )
)

val displayFontFamily = FontFamily(
    Font(
        googleFont = GoogleFont("Noto Sans"),
        fontProvider = provider,
    )
)

To add custom fonts, you'll need to head to Google Fonts and download the font families you selected in Material Theme Builder. You'll need to place all the .ttf/.otf files inside the commonMain/kotlin/yourpackage/composeResources/font folder.
Note: Unlike native Android, every time you add any resource in KMP, you'll have to rebuild the project for the changes to get reflected throughout the code.
To rebuild the project in Android Studio:
Main Menu -> Build -> Rebuild Project 

After rebuilding the project, you'll need to rewrite displayFontFamily and bodyFontFamily as composable functions and integrate them in AppTypography. Here is how I configure Noto Sans and Poppins in my project:
@Composable
fun NotoSansFontFamily() = FontFamily(
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_Thin, weight = FontWeight.Thin),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_Thin, weight = FontWeight.Thin),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_ThinItalic, weight = FontWeight.Thin, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_ExtraLight, weight = FontWeight.ExtraLight),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_ExtraLightItalic, weight = FontWeight.ExtraLight, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_Light, weight = FontWeight.Light),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_LightItalic, weight = FontWeight.Light, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_Regular, weight = FontWeight.Normal),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_Italic, weight = FontWeight.Normal, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_Medium, weight = FontWeight.Medium),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_MediumItalic, weight = FontWeight.Medium, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_SemiBold, weight = FontWeight.SemiBold),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_SemiBoldItalic, weight = FontWeight.SemiBold, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_Bold, weight = FontWeight.Bold),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_BoldItalic, weight = FontWeight.Bold, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_ExtraBold, weight = FontWeight.ExtraBold),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_ExtraBoldItalic, weight = FontWeight.ExtraBold, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_Black, weight = FontWeight.Black),
    Font(Res.font.NotoSans_BlackItalic, weight = FontWeight.Black, style = FontStyle.Italic)
)

@Composable
fun PoppinsFontFamily() = FontFamily(
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_Thin, weight = FontWeight.Thin),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_ThinItalic, weight = FontWeight.Thin, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_ExtraLight, weight = FontWeight.ExtraLight),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_ExtraLightItalic, weight = FontWeight.ExtraLight, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_Light, weight = FontWeight.Light),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_LightItalic, weight = FontWeight.Light, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_Regular, weight = FontWeight.Normal),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_Italic, weight = FontWeight.Normal, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_Medium, weight = FontWeight.Medium),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_MediumItalic, weight = FontWeight.Medium, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_SemiBold, weight = FontWeight.SemiBold),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_SemiBoldItalic, weight = FontWeight.SemiBold, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_Bold, weight = FontWeight.Bold),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_BoldItalic, weight = FontWeight.Bold, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_ExtraBold, weight = FontWeight.ExtraBold),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_ExtraBoldItalic, weight = FontWeight.ExtraBold, style = FontStyle.Italic),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_Black, weight = FontWeight.Black),
    Font(Res.font.Poppins_BlackItalic, weight = FontWeight.Black, style = FontStyle.Italic)
)

@Composable
fun AppTypography() = Typography().run {

    val displayFontFamily = NotoSansFontFamily()
    val bodyFontFamily = PoppinsFontFamily()

    copy(
        displayLarge = displayLarge.copy(fontFamily = displayFontFamily),
        displayMedium = displayMedium.copy(fontFamily = displayFontFamily),
        displaySmall = displaySmall.copy(fontFamily = displayFontFamily),
        headlineLarge = headlineLarge.copy(fontFamily = displayFontFamily),
        headlineMedium = headlineMedium.copy(fontFamily = displayFontFamily),
        headlineSmall = headlineSmall.copy(fontFamily = displayFontFamily),
        titleLarge = titleLarge.copy(fontFamily = displayFontFamily),
        titleMedium = titleMedium.copy(fontFamily = displayFontFamily),
        titleSmall = titleSmall.copy(fontFamily = displayFontFamily),
        bodyLarge = bodyLarge.copy(fontFamily =  bodyFontFamily),
        bodyMedium = bodyMedium.copy(fontFamily = bodyFontFamily),
        bodySmall = bodySmall.copy(fontFamily = bodyFontFamily),
        labelLarge = labelLarge.copy(fontFamily = bodyFontFamily),
        labelMedium = labelMedium.copy(fontFamily = bodyFontFamily),
        labelSmall = labelSmall.copy(fontFamily = bodyFontFamily)
    )
}

3. Add expect/actual functions to make the theme work across all platforms:
As you stated in the question, you'll have to add an expect function in the commonMain configuration which will act as an entry point/declaration for your theme and define the actual logic in the platform-specific configurations. I referred to this medium tutorial for the expect/actual functions.
Make these changes:
Create AppTheme.kt in the theme directory, where Color.kt, Theme.kt and Type.kt are placed. Add this code:
@Composable
expect fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean,
    dynamicColor: Boolean,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
)

Implement actual functions in all the configurations that you have in your project:
androidMain: Now, in androidMain/kotlin/yourpackage/ui/theme/ (create the directories and files that don't exist), place this code in AppTheme.kt:
@Composable
actual fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean,
    dynamicColor: Boolean,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if(darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }
        darkTheme -> darkScheme
        else -> lightScheme
    }

    val view = LocalView.current
    if(!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(
                window,
                view
            ).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = AppTypography(),
        content = content
    )

}

In MainActivity.kt, modify the App function to this:
App(
          darkTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
          dynamicColor = false,
    )

desktopMain and iosMain: In desktopMain/kotlin/yourpackage/ui/theme/, place this code in AppTheme.kt:
@Composable
actual fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean,
    dynamicColor: Boolean,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = if(darkTheme) darkScheme else lightScheme,
        typography = AppTypography(),
        content = content
    )
}

In main.kt, change App function to this:
App(
        darkTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
        dynamicColor = false,
    )

Make the same changes in iosMain/kotlin/yourpackage/ui/theme/AppTheme.kt.
For MainViewController.kt:
fun MainViewController() = ComposeUIViewController {
    val isDarkTheme =
        UIScreen.mainScreen.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle ==
                UIUserInterfaceStyle.UIUserInterfaceStyleDark
    App(
        darkTheme = isDarkTheme,
        dynamicColor = false,
    )
}

wasmJsMain: Make the same changes again in wasmJsMain/kotlin/yourpackage/ui/theme/AppTheme.kt.
For main.kt, change App function to this:
App(
        darkTheme = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
        dynamicColor = false
   )

Finally modify commonMain/kotlin/yourpackage/App.kt:
fun App(
    darkTheme: Boolean,
    dynamicColor: Boolean,
) {
    AppTheme(
        darkTheme = darkTheme,
        dynamicColor = dynamicColor
    ) {
       // your app content here
    }
}

After all of these changes have been made, rebuild the project again and run your app on any platform. You should see the theme working without any problems.
Hope this helps!
